# Timers and Threads in the Netbeans debugging window of a Codename One app

Tags: codenameone

When I debug a Codename One app in Netbeans, I get a window like the following:
[image]

I have tons of timers... is there an easy way to know who are "Timer-0", "Timer-1", "Timer-2" and "Timer-3" reported in the window? Is it possible to assign a significant name to the timers to get a more meaningful debugging window in Netbeans?

Same question for "Thread-5" reported in the window: I don't know how to discover who is it...

Thank you

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: You can switch your debugging to any thread you want and then you might see what it does: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/debug-multithreaded.html#Exercise_22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timers use the `java.util.Timer` API where there's no way to indicate this as far as I know. When you create a thread via `Display` or `CN` you can specify the thread name which is what we do for the EDT.